# Converting date to as.POSIXct in R and it subtracts two dates

Tags: r, date, datetime

I'm trying to calculate a date - 1 (basically the day before the date) in R and when it converts it to a POSIXct it seems to subtract another date?

The column is of type POSIXct:

```
class(df$Date)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Here's the initial value:

```
> df[12,"Date"]
[1] "2016-03-09 EST"
```

If I just do as.Date and subtract one it works fine:

```
as.Date(df[12,"Date"]-1, tz="EST")
[1] "2016-03-08"
```

But I'm saving it back to the same column so it converts is back to as.POSIXct automatically (I think).  And then I end up with March 7 in that column.  And 7 pm.  If I type it out here I get this:

```
as.POSIXct(as.Date(df[12,"Date"]-1, tz="EST"))
[1] "2016-03-07 19:00:00 EST"
```

I've tried using America/New York for the tz.  I've tried the as.Date around just the df[12,"Date"] or around the whole thing including the -1... I have no clue what to do!

Thanks!

Comment: If you really have dates, why use POSIX? `as.Date("2016-03-09") - 1` works fine. Heck, even `as.POSIXct("2016-03-09 EST") - 1` works in some sense. But I don't get why you'd want to move between 'em.

Comment: @Frank - it might sound strange on the surface, but I have dealt with several databases where dates of birth etc are stored as datetime (with empty time components), presumably so they can be compared easily with more specific to-the-minute variables.

Comment: I'm not very good at R, but I'm using ggplot after and it seems to only work if it's a POSIX.  It's very possible I'm also using ggplot wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `as.difftime` to take away amounts specified in units of time. It will work consistently regardless of your data being in `Date` or `POSIXct` formats. E.g.:

This fails as you described:

```
x <- as.POSIXct(c("2016-03-09","2016-03-10"), tz="US/Eastern")
#[1] "2016-03-09 EST" "2016-03-10 EST"
x[1] <- as.Date(x[1]-1, tz="US/Eastern")
#[1] "2016-03-07 19:00:00 EST" "2016-03-10 00:00:00 EST"
```

This works:

```
x <- as.POSIXct(c("2016-03-09","2016-03-10"), tz="US/Eastern")
#[1] "2016-03-09 EST" "2016-03-10 EST"
x[1] <- x[1] - as.difftime(1, units="days")
#[1] "2016-03-08 EST" "2016-03-10 EST"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do what Frank mentioned in the comments,

You should consider using `strptime` instead of `as.POSIXct`

To ensure it returns in a `POSIXct` format use:

```
strptime(df[12,"Date"]-1,tz="EST",format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: I suspect the as.Date isn't doing anything essential here based on `x = as.POSIXct("2016-03-09 EST"); strptime(x-1,tz="EST",format="%Y-%m-%d")` seeming to work.

Comment: Yup. I think it wouldn't make a difference. I didn't realize that the `Date` column was already in Date format. I'll make the edit! Thanks!